# a light GUI program for a chime at preset interval(s)?

Tags: linux, web-apps, alarm-clock

I know 2 programs, that can do this already on linux: `kalarm` and `alarm-clock-applet`. Both are heavy, `kalarm` due to akonadi and about 200MB of dependencies, `alarm-clock-applet` takes up CPU time, when checked with `top`, which is absurd for an alarm app.

I would like a recurring chime, at say, 1h (:00), 30m (:00 and :30). It can be a web app in addition to being a native app (though, it could be argued, that a web app is even heavier than `kalarm`).

`Blip Blip` under android is a good example of what I want (running it in a virtual machine is out of the question, please no VM solutions, not even java).

Answer (score 1):

I found this:

https://awakeningbell.org/

and one can install `Blip Blip` inside `Chrome`:

https://archon-runtime.github.io/

Though, I am mentioning this as a curiosity.